# Trying to make an automatic custom dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am trying to make a custom dialog with lottie animation (a dialog that just contains a progress animation), that automatically close after 2000ms.
Used the code below to show .The problem is Dialog doesn't close after 2000ms. please help me .How can i do that.
The method code is given below.

```
final Dialog lottieProgressbarDialog = new Dialog(this);

View lottieProgressbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lottieprogressbar, null);

lottieProgressbarDialog.setContentView(lottieProgressbarView);
lottieProgressbarDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
lottieProgressbarDialog.setCancelable(false);
lottieProgressbarDialog.show();

if (!_show) {
    lottieProgressbarDialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Try using `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 0):

why not make a use of `Timer`?

just try this-->

```
 final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            lottieProgressbarDialog.dismiss(); //close the dialog
            t.cancel();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler`

```
    lottieProgressbarDialog.show();
    
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
     if(passwordDialog.isShowing()){
       lottieProgressbarDialog.dismiss();
     }
    },2000);
```